# .desktop files don't display icons

Tags: 20.04, icons, .desktop

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I want to change some icons, so I opened `/usr/share/applications` to see the `.desktop` files for the installed applications. But the `.desktop` files don't display their icons (as shown in the screenshot), so I don't know which icons I should change.

[image: .desktop files with no icons]

How can I make the `.desktop` files display their icons?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the application, then you can try to find the right `.desktop` file by grepping a directory listing of where the files live, for example:

```
$ ls /usr/share/applications | grep -i calculator
org.gnome.Calculator.desktop
```

If you do not know the application, or the `.desktop` name has an unexpected name, then you could attempt locating the file based on the name indicated under the icon in the application overview with the find command, e.g.

```
$ find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H Name=Calculator {} \; 2>/dev/null
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop:Name=Calculator
```

This searches the contents of all `.desktop` files that contain the listed name as the `Name=` attribute.

These are ways to locate the `.desktop` launcher of which you want to change the icon.